# How to convert a sum into a definite integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

I know there is some way to convert a sum into an integral, and vice versa. However, I am very confused on how actually to do this, and if there is some sort of intuition behind it.

*Note*: I'm **not** asking for the limit definition of a definite integral.

Comment: Like [Abel's summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Not exactly, more like a general way to convert sums to integrals and vice versa. Although that link is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that? :-)

Comment: @A.Donda I agree with Op. The technique is somewhat trivial...The moment I saw $A(x)$ defined as a summation I was like "Wow, way to be circular!"

Comment: @Zach466920, I'm not saying he is wrong, I'm just curious where he got that information from. A gap in my mathematical education I guess...

Comment: @A.Donda I wasn't familiar with it either :)

Comment: Are you referring by any chance to the process of expanding the integrand into its Taylor or binomial series, for instance, and then reversing the order of summation and integration ?

Comment: @Lucian I'm not exactly sure. I don't know much about the process.